# Reading from a file and inserting it into an array, Java

Tags: java

I am getting a run time error this code.

I am reading from a file into putting the data into an array and then using an insertion sort algorithm to sort it and print the result

What is causing my run time error? This is the run time error:java.util.InputMismatchException

The following is what the file contains:
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738
44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class InsertionSortExample { 
  private static int [] arr1;
  
  public static void main(String[]args){  
    String fileName = "Data.txt"; //adds file as string
    try{
      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));//looks at the file
      while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){//while there is another line in the file
        String inputLine = fileScan.nextLine(); //adds that line to a string
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputLine); //looks at each line
        for(int i = 0; i < inputLine.length(); i++){ //reads through the line
          arr1[i] = scan.nextInt(); //adds each element to an array
        }
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("File not found. Check file name and location."); // if theres no dile itll say
      System.exit(1);
    }
   
    insertionSort(arr1);//sorting array using insertion sort    
    for(int member:arr1){    
      System.out.print(member +" ");  //prints out each element of the array
    }
  }    
  
  public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {  
    int n = array.length;  //length of the array
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {  //for each member of the array
      int key = array[j];  
      int i = j-1;  
      while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) {  
        array [i+1] = array [i];  
        i--;  
      }  
      array[i+1] = key; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see a space inside the 2nd line of your input? Is that typo? or it might be about that.

Comment: @ChayneP.S. That is a typo

Comment: Can you pinpoint which line throws the error?

Comment: @ChayneP.S. at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know why.. For int, the limit of number is around 2 billion.. or 10 digits. Your numbers are much bigger. Even long cannot be that big.. Maybe using BigInteger instead? but your sort function will need to be changed.

Comment: My file had no spaces in-between values, so that fixed that run time error. I used a python to run through the file and add spaces between every number in the file.